# What resources are available for building a cutting-edge Linux box?

Tags: linux, drivers, compatibility

One of the problems with loving both Linux and sweet new hardware is that you're never sure what's supported (i.e. driver availability).

How can I easily determine if those shiny things in your shopping cart will work on your Linux distro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start with looking at your distro of choice's homepage.

Here's one hardware compatibility list:

http://www.linux-drivers.org/

Answer (score 1):

These days, I've never really had an issue with hardware compatibility, and modern linux distros.